# Angular: directive toggles disabled status overrides ng-disabled accidentally

Tags: angularjs, forms, toggle, directive

I am trying to create a directive called `toggle-field` that supports toggling disabled/enabled status for input/button fields in a form. [The plnker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdgU3N07ghXWVBQEU4Zs?p=preview). So far my directive works in a way that can disable the input and button that do not have `ng-disabled` directive. The problem is with the buttons that already have ng-disabled, for example:

```
<button type="submit" toggle-field class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="test_form.$invalid" ng-click="vm.submit()">Submit</button>
```

**The link function in the directive is as following:**

```
function toggleField($log, $compile) {

    var directive = {
      link: link,
      require: '?ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true
    };

    var originalNgDisabledVal = '';

    return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      //enabled

      if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('ngDisabled')) {
        originalNgDisabledVal = attrs.ngDisabled;
        $log.info('attrs.ngDisabled value: ' + scope.$eval(attrs.ngDisabled));
      }

      scope.$on('enabled', function() {
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('ngDisabled')) {
          element.show();
          //attrs.$set('ngDisabled', originalNgDisabledVal); //not working
        } else {
          element.removeAttr('disabled');
        }

      });

      //disabled
      scope.$on('disabled', function() {
        if (!attrs.hasOwnProperty('ngDisabled')) {
          attrs.$set('disabled', 'disabled');

        } else {
          //attrs.$set('ngDisabled', true); //not working
          element.hide();
        }
      });
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    } //link
}
```

As a workaround in the above code, I use the element.show() or element.hide() on fields that already have **ng-disabled**, but I would really like to make it work for disabled. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be ok if your directive removes ng-disabled on the elements that already have it ?

Comment: no, we need to keep the ng-disabled if it's already there. This is import for form validation purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're going overkill doing this in the link function. You're link function should actually be pretty empty (completely empty in this case). Here's a plunkr with the solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KVeprA9qbqlkwvg9Bafx?p=preview

The link function is completely empty:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  //enabled

  //$log.info('outherHTML: ' + element[0].outerHTML);

} //link
```

And then in the html you can pivot off enabled or not:

```
<input type="text" id="username" ng-disabled="!vm.enabled" toggle-field="" class="form-control col-sm-9" ng-model="vm.username" required="" />
<input type="password" id="password" ng-disabled="!vm.enabled" toggle-field="" class="form-control col-sm-9" ng-model="vm.password" />
<button type="submit" toggle-field="" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!vm.enabled || test_form.$invalid" ng-click="vm.submit()">Submit</button>
```

I don't even think you need a directive to handle doing this, you can do it just in the dom.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have considered using ng-disabled directly, but we need to do this site-wide. Putting the `vm.enabled` in every scope/controller should be avoided as per the requirements. That's why I resort to a custom directive.

Comment: How many form partials do you have? Can you refactor a form into a directive if it is being used multiple times?

Comment: The number of forms is more than 15 and is till counting up, and each form has more than 10 fields (input/select, etc). It would be too much work to add a `vm.enabled` to every scope to the forms.

Comment: Right, but the forms aren't dynamic and you're only creating them once. Angular is built to do what I'm suggesting and I would recommend going down that path. While the task may be daunting with the 15 forms you have now, once you've finished with those 15 having a new form wire up will be trivial.